# Swap tokens to Ether on Uniswap V2 TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development

I am trying to swap DAI to ETH on kovan testnet my wallet and contract both have DAI tokens. Whenever I swap the token through web3 the transaction fails `Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'`
and it says on Tenderly about `Dai/insufficient-balance` as an error. I don't understand why this happen and how to resolve this. Here is the snippet of the Sell.

```
onSell = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    
    const tokenAmount = web3.utils.toWei(this.state.SellValue, 'ether');
    const requiredEth = await frontrun.methods.getEstimatedTokenforETH(tokenAmount).call();
    
    this.setState({ message: 'Transaction Processing ...'});

    try {
      await dai.methods.approve('0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D', tokenAmount).send({from: this.state.accounts[0]}) // change to variable
      
      await myContract.methods.Sell(tokenAmount).send({
        from: this.state.accounts[0],
        value: requiredEth[1] // change this to price oracle
      });

      this.setState({ message: 'Transaction successfully completed!'});
    } catch (err) {

      this.setState({ message: 'Transaction failed!'});

    }

  }
```

I used the router address of uniswap for the first argument on the `approve` and I tried changing that to the contract address or spender address and still I get the error.

Comment: did you found a solution? I'm having the same problem. I have aproved the uniswap router address but I can not add liquidity